# Imprimir elementos de un bucle For en AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android

He creado un programa que recibe los elementos de una progresión aritmética (Primer término, razón y número de términos) y devuelve todos los términos de la progresión y la suma de esos términos. La suma la muestra bien, pero cuando quiero ver todos los términos solo me muestra el último.

Aquí está mi código. Como dije, todo funciona bien lo único que no me sale es que se muestren todos los términos de la progresión:

```
public void mostrarProgresion(View view){
    asignarDatos();
    //n1=Primer Término
    //n2=Razón
    //n3=Número de Términos
    total=n2*n3;
    if (n1>=n3){
        total+=n1;
    }
    for (int i=n1;i<total;i=i+n2){
        txvres.setText(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema está aquí:

```
for (int i=n1;i<total;i=i+n2){
    txvres.setText(i);
}
```

Con `setText` indicas el texto que se va a mostrar, y tal y como lo estás haciendo, en cada pasada el bucle lo actualizas al siguiente término. Entonces cuando termina el bucle, has mostrado y sobrescrito todos los términos quedando sólo el último como visible. No es que te muestre sólo el último término, los ha mostrado todos y los ha sobrescrito todos.

Si lo que quieres es que te los muestre todos al mismo tiempo, lo que podrías hacer es leer el texto (por ejemplo con `getText`)  y concatenarle el nuevo valor al final (OJO porque no he usado Android Studio en mucho tiempo y no lo he probado y seguramente contenga fallos):

```
for (int i=n1;i<total;i=i+n2){
    txvres.setText( txvres.getText() + ", " + i );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que dice @AlvaroMontoro es totalmente cierto, estas mostrando cada término en cada iteración pero los estás sobreescribiendo. Una alternativa a la que te comenta Alvaro podría ser la siguiente en la que vas concatenando todos los términos en un `string` y luego los muestres todos al mismo tiempo:

```
String terminos = "";

for (int i=n1;i<total;i=i+n2){
    terminos += ", " + i;
}

txvres.setText(terminos);
```